# I keep getting Exception thrown: System.InvalidOperationException with signalr

Tags: signalr, blazor, webassembly

I've got a table in my blazor webassembly client side application which broadcasts data from an sql server.
I've set up signalr to every 5 seconds which will grab the new data and push the data to the table so the clients get real time data every 5 seconds.
Blazor radzen provides an edit table function which allows users to edit the details of certain columns and then save that change and push it to the database.
But everytime that I use this edit function and save, I get an error saying:
"Exception thrown: System.InvalidOperationException in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll".
Here is my code:

Radzen Grid Table:

```
<div class="row">
   <h1>Servers</h1>
   <RadzenGrid @ref="serversGrid" AllowFiltering="true" 
   FilterCaseSensitivity="Radzen.FilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive"
   AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" Data="@serverData" TItem="Server"
   ColumnWidth="200px" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" PageSize="10">
      <Columns>
          <RadzenGridColumn TItem="Server" Property="ServerIp" Title="IP" />
          <RadzenGridColumn TItem="Server" Property="Status" Title="Status">
            <EditTemplate Context="server">
               <RadzenDropDown @bind-Value="server.Status" Data="@statusList" Style="width:100%"/>
            </EditTemplate>
          </RadzenGridColumn>
     </Columns>
  </RadzenGrid>
```

SignalR timer code:

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            StartTimer();
        }
        private void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            _timer.Interval = 5000;
            _timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsedHandler;

            _timer.Start();
        }
```

On elapsed, the timer will call signalr to get data and replace the data with the newer version of it.

```
public async Task BroadcastServers()
        {
            var data = _serverService.GetServers().Result; //get data from service
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ServerBroadcast", data); //send data to all clients
            
        }
```

I also get another error which says:
The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached entity framework core.

I've searched this error up and still I've got no solution.

Please help! Thank you

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` usually contains an exception message that indicates the problem.  This exception is a general catchall used throughout the framework, so please provide the actual error message.  Also include the first few lines of the stack trace.

Comment: When you are submitting edits through grid from UI, in the back end at the same time signalr is trying to update the same rows. It's data concurrency issue. Check your dbcontext instances. You might have to create a separate instance of DB context for both of the operations. Search up "ef core dbcontext using statement ". I hope this helps you.

Comment: You can also turn on "Enablesensitivelogging" using something like below, this will show more information about which Id is being tracked by ef core and giving you error. services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnection")); options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true); });